# Script to restart the application

Tags: shell-script, cron, services

I need to write a script for the below scenario in Linux:

- Run a cron every 5 minutes.
- `grep` the application log file to see if we can see the pattern "ORA-".
- If we see this pattern:

  - stop the service.
  - Rename the application log file with timestamp appended.
  - Start the service.

So each time there is a problem, within 5 minutes the application will get restarted.

Comment: There would be better to rewrite your daemon: when it will be started first time, it will save old logs. In case of falling, you can restart it by init: just write your daemon in `/etc/inittab` with parameter `respawn`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ grep -q "ORA-" $logfile ]; then {
   service $whatever stop;
   mv $logfile $logfile+$(date +%format)
   service $whatever start;
} fi
```

Or something similar. 
I can't actually test it but if there's no syntax error on if and you take the correct format that should work. You could, in case, check if service's pid's present.